# Saving loop results in new dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, loops

I try to save results of a for loop in new columns but despite message() returns proper information, the data is not saved.

Background:
I have a data frame which in column 1 carries XPaths and in column 2 CSS Selectors of website elements and wish to save results of getComputedStyle (JS function evaluated with the help of RSelenium) for several styles like 'color', 'width' etc.

```
#Function filling one row with CSS's
get_computed_styles_loop <- function(some_web_element){
  for (style in 1:length(css_styles)) {
    js_function_styles <- paste("return window.getComputedStyle(",some_web_element,").getPropertyValue('",css_styles[style],"')",sep="")
    my_df_col <- columns_number + as.integer(style)
    my_df[selector, my_df_col] <- as.character(remDr$executeScript(js_function_styles)) # <- THIS ONE DOESN'T SAVE DATA TO THE DATAFRAME
    message(paste(js_function_styles, " ", my_df_col , " ", remDr$executeScript(js_function_styles)))
  }
}
```

```
#Filling the whole dataframe
for (selector in 1:nrow(my_df){
  js_function_xpath <- paste("document.getElementByXPath('",my_df[selector,1],"')",sep="");  
  js_function_selector <- paste("document.querySelector('",my_df[selector,2],"')",sep="");
      tryCatch({
        get_computed_styles_loop(js_function_xpath)
      },
      error=function(cond){
        message(paste("XPath not working here: ", selector))
        tryCatch({
          get_computed_styles_loop(js_function_selector)
        },
        error=function(cond1){
          message(paste("Neither does CSS Selector: ", selector))
          return(NA)
        }  
        )
      }  
      )
}
```

#### Exemplary message() results. It seems ok but it's not shown in new columns:

```
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('color')   22   rgb(17, 17, 17)
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('background-color')   23   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('background')   24   
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('margin')   25   
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('padding')   26   
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('width')   27   400px
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('height')   28   32px
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('font-weight')   29   400
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('font-family')   30   "Open Sans", sans-serif
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('font-size')   31   13px
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('border')   32   
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('border-radius')   33   
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('position')   34   static
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('text-align')   35   start
return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByXPath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table')).getPropertyValue('pointer')   36
```

Comment: `message` operates completely in side-effect, nothing is returned (see `(message("hello"))` giving you `NULL`). Further, a `for` loop returns nothing. I suggest using `lapply` with explicitly returning the string you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use lapply but I'm not sure why this one: `my_df[selector, my_df_col] <- as.character(remDr$executeScript(js_function_styles))` is not evaluated. Does it work solely within the scope of the function and just because there's no `return` it won't work?

Comment: Okay, I see more of what you're talking about here. Your function is a little confusing, to be honest, not the least of which is that it reference variables from all over ("scope breach", and it can be very difficult to trace/debug functions that do this). I can't really reproduce this (don't have your data, I know little about `RSelenium`, etc). I'm guessing that this has nothing to do with `RSelenium`, so it should be feasible for you to provide sample data (with `dput`) and simplify the problem in order to use it.